# node.js how to use a app.get variable in another one

Tags: node.js, express, multer

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
   can = req.originalUrl.split('&')[0];
});
```

I want to use `can` in storage for change `var dir`

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        console.dir(req.originalUrl)
        var dir = './uploads';
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
        callback(null, dir);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname);
    }
});
```

I tried to make global.can but it's not worked.

Comment: If you're trying to save something from a GET request for use in a future request from that user, the first choice would be don't.  Save it in the client and then send it back to the server when the server actually needs it.  That's better stateless http.  If you really have to save something on behalf of the user on the server, then you will need something like a server session object (e.g. `express-session`).

Comment: FYI, it looks like a big server vulnerability if you're letting a user specify an unsanitized directory value on your server.  There are all sorts of risks associated with that.

Comment: People could offer better help if you showed the entire problem of what you're trying to do because there is likely a way better approach than what you're attempting here,.

Comment: Thanks for answer, actually i want to make a upload services which upload folder will change dynamically. And is just for my self to upload images, so it's not public.

Comment: The short answer is "look up how to sessions in Express" because if you want one URL call to your server from a user to affect how some future call for that same user works, you're clearly tracking users across multiple calls and that's the very definition of a session.

Comment: If you're just changing a global setting for your server from a privileged admin login, you can just store the value in a variable on your server and then just reference that variable in other places.  If you want the change to last even if your server is restarted, you will have to also store that change to some sort of config file that your server reads upon startup.